# allow external server to access a server with no dns using php

Tags: php, dns

My development servers are external "dev.site.com"

We have our database on an external IP address, but there is no DNS records for it. DNS has been set up locally using hosts files.

For example: database.site.com 55.444.33.21

Since my external development server cannot resolve database.site.com or 55.444.33.21 independently, nor can I add local DNS records to the server, how can I properly access it?

Is there some method in PHP I can utilize to essentially create an on-the-fly DNS for?

I do not have the ability to change how anything is setup, but I have full control of the codebase which is PHP. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to say 55.444.33.21 = database.site.com in my script so whenever I call database.site.com in code it works.

**EDIT**
I am not able to access it with just the ip, and i cannot add it to the local hosts file on the server. My goal is to find a workaround to these issues.

Comment: Can't you just access it from the IP address?

Comment: Alternatively you could set up the record in your hosts file on your external development machine.

Comment: Based on your edit: If you're not able to access the server with the IP, then how are you able to access the server *at all*?

Comment: @david i am able to access the server when i have records setup within my hosts file locally. If I access just the ip, I get an "under construction" page. If i try with the domain I get nothing as there is no dns for it.

Comment: @RyanHartman: Ah, there's the missing piece of information.  The server has multiple virtual hosts and only knows how to route the request if the request includes the hostname.  _That_ is a much more critical piece of information in this issue :)  There might be a perfectly good workaround outside of code, so you can re-ask the question in a more server/network way over on Server Fault.  The issue from that angle is one of trying to route the request to the proper virtual host without the hostname in the request.

Comment: What PHP methods you use to access the site ? - is it PECL HTTP, streams or cURL or what ? Does it use SSL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call "database.site.com" in code.

Instead, define a constant in *one place* in the code and use that constant throughout the rest of the code:

```
define("DATABASE_SERVER", "database.site.com");
```

or

```
const DATABASE_SERVER = "database.site.com";
```

Then throughout the code you'd use that constant instead of the actual value.  So when you need to move the code to another environment, you configure it for that environment by changing the value of the constant:

```
define("DATABASE_SERVER", "55.444.33.21");
```

or

```
const DATABASE_SERVER = "55.444.33.21";
```

In general, you want to use actual dynamic values as little as possible in the code.  This gives all of your code multiple reasons to change.  The value should be abstracted behind a constant or variable or symbol of some kind so that, if the value changes, only that one piece of code has a reason to change.  The rest continues to function.

Comment: Thank you for the reply David, unfortunately this doesn't address the domain name resolution issue :(

Comment: @RyanHartman: Maybe the issue was unclear then?  You don't need to "resolve" the actual IP address.  That would be accessible globally without the use of DNS.  From the question it sounds as simple as one environment needing to use a different address than another environment.  That's where application configuration comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack, but you can `define("database.site.com", "55.444.33.21");`

Comment: That won't quite work, because it would define it as the variable `database.site.com` instead of replacing the string `'database.site.com'`